# direct upload from google drive to amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I have a working upload form in my webapp that lets user upload files from their computer.
The file is uploaded directly to amazon s3 without going through my server first

this is how my form looks like, and Im using jquery file upload plugin.

```
    <form class="startfileupload" action="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<?php echo AMAZON_S3_BUCKET ?>/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $file_name;?>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<?php echo AMAZON_KEY ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
        <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<?php echo $aws['base64Policy']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $aws['signature']; ?>">
        <input id="uploadinput" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.bmp,
            .pdf, .zip" name="file" multiple=""/>
```

I want to give users the option for users to choose files from their google drive, using the drive api I added the google picker which lets user pick files from there.

after they pick the file, I get in the callback the file metadata (including a file url).

How can I use that to upload the file directly to s3?

I dont want to upload the file to my server and then copy it to s3, I want to upload the file dircetly to s3. Is that poosible without having to download the file on client side and then upload it?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

The only way to upload a file to S3 is to send the *file* to S3.

S3 does not have the capability to fetch an object from an external URL.

Download to your server directly from Google and then upload to S3, or you could use AWS Lambda invoked through AWS API Gateway to handle the actual download/upload transfer in the background (sync or async).

Comment: ok i see, so a follow up question, how can I use the link I got to download that file to my server? the server is not authnticated with the user credentials, so how can he access the file to download it?

Comment: you dont. you download it on the client side using Javascript, then post to s3. bo server involved.

Comment: Is there a way to sync Google Drive and S3?

Comment: Is this resolved by any means ? I am thinking of using Rclone for this.

Answer (score 2):

from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

! apt-get update

! apt install awscli

! aws configure. #Give credentials

! aws s3 cp 'drive/MyDrive/PathToFolder/' s3://path

Comment: Mount your drive in colab and copy directly from google drive to s3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).