# How to transfer file from google drive to amazon s3 storage?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I am able to get the file id from google drive and the webContentLink from the google.files.list() from JS SDK.But when i want to upload it in s3 ,i have to download the file in my local server.Is there any way to avoid it?.

Comment: According to an answer in [SO 33215197](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215197/direct-upload-from-google-drive-to-amazon-s3), the only way to upload a file to S3 is to send the file to S3. S3 does not have the capability to fetch an object from an external URL.

Comment: I am able to upload a file directly without storing into local by sending the response from google drive sdk into s3 body as it also accept buffer data,so there is no requirement of storing.

Comment: @ShubhanshuRanjan Can you please explain your solution ?

Comment: you are going to have to transfer the file to something you control (i.e. your local machine, a cloud server) so that you can then upload it to S3.  There is no direct Google to AWS integration... even with the solution that Shubhanshu proposed, you are still downloading the file, just keeping it in memory before pushing to S3 instead of storing on the filesystem.